# Getting image from Webview to ImageView

Tags: java, android, webview

I have a custom `WebView`. Inside it I've got an image. The `WebView` is zoomable. I want to reset zoom when I click a button, extract image from there and place inside `ImageView`.

So far, with the help of  [x-code](https://stackoverflow.com/users/283113/x-code) I've managed to write this in `onClickListener`:

```
while (wv2.zoomOut()){
    wv2.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(wv2.getDrawingCache());
    bitmapPath = bitmap;
    wv2.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            SaveImage(bitmap);
        }
    }).start();

    tstImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

The `WebView` zooms out completely, but the `Bitmap` I get in `ImageView` is slightly zoomed in. I need to click 1 more time to get the whole `bitmap` inside the `ImageView`

Comment: What is the XML layout for your web view?

Comment: did you try this?

`webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);`

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the Javadoc of [`WebView.getDrawingCache()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getDrawingCache%28boolean%29) method explains your problem.

> `public Bitmap getDrawingCache (boolean autoScale)`
>
> ...
>
> Note about auto scaling in compatibility mode: When auto scaling is
>   not enabled, this method will create **a bitmap of the same size as this
>   view**. Because this bitmap will be drawn scaled by the parent
>   ViewGroup, the **result on screen might show scaling artifacts**. **To avoid
>   such artifacts, you should call this method by setting the auto
>   scaling to true**. Doing so, however, will generate a bitmap of a
>   different size than the view. This implies that your application must
>   be able to handle this size.

In your code you simply have to make this change

```
bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(wv2.getDrawingCache(true));
```